# JIT Assembler for C# language

Tags: c#, assembly, jit, fasm

I'm writing a memory editing library and I'm interested in writing asm code on the fly in C#. I especially like FASM, so I found a library called Fasm_managed that can assemble my x86 asm code on the fly. Now, I'm hurting a problem, I need to assemble x64 code too, but unfortunately, this library doesn't support it.

Does anyone knows a good JIT assembler library for C# that compiles both x86/x64 asm code (ideally FASM syntax) ? :)

A good example of what I'm looking for is the library [AsmJit](http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/) (but this one is only for C/C++).

Thanks guys.

Comment: Why not use AsmJit from C#? You could create a wrapper library in C++ and then link to that from C# if that would make it easier.